# Cassandra aggregation to second table

Tags: cassandra, aggregate-functions

i have a cassandra table like:

```
CREATE TABLE sensor_data (
  sensor VARCHAR,
  timestamp timestamp,
  value float,
  PRIMARY KEY ((sensor), timestamp) 
)
```

And and aggregation table.

```
CREATE TABLE sensor_data_aggregated (
  sensor VARCHAR,
  aggregation VARCHAR  /* hour or day */
  timestamp timestamp,
  aggragation
  min_timestamp timestamp,
  min_value float,
  max_timestamp timestamp,
  max_value float,
  avg_value float,
  PRIMARY KEY ((sensor, aggregation), timestamp) 
)
```

Is there a possibility of any trigger, to fill the "sensor_data_aggregated" table automaticly on insert, update, delete or "sensor_data" table?

My current solution whould be to write an custom trigger, with second commit log.
And an application that read and truncate this log peridicly to generate the aggregated data.

But i also found information that the datastax ops center can do this but no instruction how to do that?

What will be the best solution how to to this?

Answer (score 2):

You can implement your own [C* trigger](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/trigger_r.html) for that, which will execute additional queries for your aggregation table after each row insert into `sensor_data`.

Also, for maintaining min/max values you can use [CAS and C* lightweight transactions](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/lightweight-transactions-in-cassandra-2-0) like

```sql
update sensor_data_aggregated 
set min_value=123 
where 
  sensor='foo' 
  and aggregation='bar' 
  and ts='2015-01-01 00:00:00' 
if min_value>123;
```

using a bit updated schema ('timestamp' is a reserved keyword in cql3, you cannot use it unescaped):

```sql
CREATE TABLE sensor_data_aggregated (
  sensor text,
  aggregation text,
  ts timestamp,
  min_timestamp timestamp,
  min_value float,
  max_timestamp timestamp,
  max_value float,
  avg_value float,
  PRIMARY KEY ((sensor, aggregation), ts) 
)
```

Comment: Sorry, can you please specify you answer a litle more? This dont work. https://gist.github.com/GreenRover/699e419de7b178e01c20 How would it be right?

Comment: I've updated my answer. The original one's idea was mostly correct, but with 2 cql3 syntax errors :)

Comment: But how should i replace your fixed values like "123" "foo" "bar" .. with the values of the current running INSERT?

Comment: You can use your hands to write code that either generates the query with your values, or use prepared statements.

Comment: Ok is there also an solution to do this automatically on insert in the main table? perhaps with java trigger?

Comment: To execute additional queries on insert implement your own [trigger](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/trigger_r.html) as I told you in the original answer.